# Particular case of the n-degree equation.

Tags: diophantine-equations

It's know that there isn't a general formula for solve the general n-degree equation for $n>4$, but there is any formula to solve the case? $A^x+A=C$ where $A$ is the variable and $A,C$ are positive integers?

Comment: I suppose you are looking for roots in $\mathbf C$... What are the possible values of $x$ and $C$ ?

Comment: $$x$$ and $$C$$ can be any value. For example $$A^6+A=66$$,

Comment: My question was more general. Can $x$ or $C$ be negative, real or complex valued ?

Comment: Also, just use one `$` to put you math equation inline.

Comment: No, the possible values are only integers, with $A,C>0$

Comment: Then you put wrong tags to you question. It should be tagged as diophantine equation or someting related to it.